# sgx-pytorch remote attestation failed due to msg3 type not matched

Tags: security, pytorch, intel, sgx, remote-attestation

I am trying to run SGX-Pytorch.
https://github.com/intel/sgx-pytorch/tree/sgx

I successfully followed [enclaves_op](https://github.com/intel/sgx-pytorch/tree/sgx/enclave_ops)'s instructions for setting up the environment. Prior to running a secure model in SGX, it is necessary to run "dkeycache" and perform remote attestation through "dkeyserver". However, I encountered an error during remote attestation where it indicated that msg3 was not matching.

Please note that the default remote attestation provided by SGX SDK works well, and msg three was also successfully verified. But for SGX-Pytorch, it is not working.

Here are the logs:

```
dhar@SGX-server:~/temp/sgx-pytorch/enclave_ops/deployment/bin/dkeycache$ sudo ./dkeycache 
Connect dkeyserver success!
Call sgx_ra_get_msg1_ex success, the MSG1 body generated.
Sending MSG1 to remote attestation service provider, and expecting MSG2 back...
MSG2 recieved success!
Call sgx_ra_proc_msg2_ex success.
Sending MSG3 to remote attestation service provider,expecting attestation result msg back...
Error, the attestaion MSG's type is not matched!

Call enclave_ra_close success.
Failed(-1) to setup the secure channel.
failed to initialize the dkeycache service.
dkeycache service is ON...



dhar@SGX-server:~/temp/sgx-pytorch/enclave_ops/deployment/bin/dkeyserver$ sudo ./dkeyserver 
Waiting for incoming connections...
New Client(4) connected! IP=127.0.0.1
receive the msg type(1) from client.
Dispatching TYPE_RA_MSG1, body size: 68
send response success with msg type(2)
receive the msg type(3) from client.
Dispatching TYPE_RA_MSG3, body size: 4936
cert_key_type = 0x5
    Error: sgx_qv_get_quote_supplemental_data_size failed: 0x0000
    Info: App: sgx_qv_verify_quote successfully returned.
    Info: App: Verification quote_verification_result=0xa003
verify result is not expected (0xa003)
failed(-1) to handle msg type(3)
send response success with msg type(3)
```

Has anyone worked with sgx-pytorch before? I would greatly appreciate any assistance.